# How to correctly solve x/x = 1 in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, equation, solver

When solving the equation x/x = 1, the solution set should be the reals without the number 0, because the expression x/x is not defined when x is 0. However, `sympy.solveset` returns the entire set of reals as the solution, like so :

```
>>> import sympy as S
>>> x = S.Symbol('x')
>>> S.solveset(S.Eq(x/x,1),domain=S.Reals)
Reals
```

Is there a way to remove the set of values for which either member of the equation is not defined ?

Comment: Interesting; the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html) shows a similar example (`sin(x)/x`) that *does* exclude 0, yielding `({2*n*pi | n in Integers} \ {0}) U ({2*n*pi + pi | n in Integers} \ {0})`

Comment: One difference: you are explicitly asking for the relation `x/x == 1`, rather than just `x/x`.

Comment: @chepner What is interesting about the documentation that you link to is that the example that you refer to is followed by another example which differs only in having `positive = True` but which *does* include 0 in the solution set.

Comment: If you print `x/x` you'll see that it evaluates to 1 before `solveset` is even called.